# Kubernetes Cinder volumes do not mount with cloud-provider=openstack

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to use the cinder plugin for kubernetes to create both statically defined PVs as well as StorageClasses, but I see no activity between my cluster and cinder for creating/mounting the devices.

Kubernetes Version:

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"4", GitVersion:"v1.4.1", GitCommit:"33cf7b9acbb2cb7c9c72a10d6636321fb180b159", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2016-10-10T18:19:49Z", GoVersion:"go1.6.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"4", GitVersion:"v1.4.1", GitCommit:"33cf7b9acbb2cb7c9c72a10d6636321fb180b159", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2016-10-10T18:13:36Z", GoVersion:"go1.6.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

The command kubelet was started with and its status:

```
systemctl status kubelet -l
● kubelet.service - Kubelet service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2016-10-20 07:43:07 PDT; 3h 53min ago
  Process: 2406 ExecStartPre=/usr/local/bin/install-kube-binaries (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2400 ExecStartPre=/usr/local/bin/create-certs (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2408 (kubelet)
   CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
           ├─2408 /usr/local/bin/kubelet --pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests --api-servers=https://172.17.0.101:6443 --logtostderr=true --v=12 --allow-privileged=true --hostname-override=jk-kube2-master --pod-infra-container-image=pause-amd64:3.0 --cluster-dns=172.31.53.53 --cluster-domain=occloud --cloud-provider=openstack --cloud-config=/etc/cloud.conf
```

Here is my cloud.conf file:

```
# cat /etc/cloud.conf
[Global]
username=<user>
password=XXXXXXXX
auth-url=http://<openStack URL>:5000/v2.0
tenant-name=Shadow
region=RegionOne
```

It appears that k8s is able to communicate successfully with openstack.  From /var/log/messages:

```
kubelet: I1020 11:43:51.770948    2408 openstack_instances.go:41] openstack.Instances() called
kubelet: I1020 11:43:51.836642    2408 openstack_instances.go:78] Found 39 compute flavors
kubelet: I1020 11:43:51.836679    2408 openstack_instances.go:79] Claiming to support Instances
kubelet: I1020 11:43:51.836688    2408 openstack_instances.go:124] NodeAddresses(jk-kube2-master) called
kubelet: I1020 11:43:52.274332    2408 openstack_instances.go:131] NodeAddresses(jk-kube2-master) => [{InternalIP 172.17.0.101} {ExternalIP 10.75.152.101}]
```

My PV/PVC yaml files, and cinder list output:

```
# cat persistentVolume.yaml
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: jk-test
  labels:
    type: test
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  cinder:
    volumeID: 48d2d1e6-e063-437a-855f-8b62b640a950
    fsType: ext4

# cat persistentVolumeClaim.yaml
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: myclaim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      type: "test"
# cinder list | grep jk-cinder
| 48d2d1e6-e063-437a-855f-8b62b640a950 | available |              jk-cinder              |  10  |      -      |  false   |
```

As seen above, cinder reports the device with the ID referenced in the pv.yaml file is available.  When I create them, things seem to work:

```
NAME         CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   RECLAIMPOLICY   STATUS    CLAIM             REASON    AGE
pv/jk-test   10Gi       RWO           Retain          Bound     default/myclaim             5h
NAME               STATUS    VOLUME    CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   AGE
pvc/myclaim        Bound     jk-test   10Gi       RWO           5h
```

Then I try to create a pod using the pvc, but it fails to mount the volume:

```
# cat testPod.yaml
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: jk-test3
  labels:
    name: jk-test
spec:
  containers:
    - name: front-end
      image: example-front-end:latest
      ports:
        - hostPort: 6000
          containerPort: 3000
  volumes:
    - name: jk-test
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: myclaim
```

And here is the state of the pod:

```
  3h            46s             109     {kubelet jk-kube2-master}                       Warning         FailedMount     Unable to mount volumes for pod "jk-test3_default(0f83368f-96d4-11e6-8243-fa163ebfcd23)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "jk-test3"/"default". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[jk-test]
  3h            46s             109     {kubelet jk-kube2-master}                       Warning         FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "jk-test3"/"default". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[jk-test]
```

I've verified that my openstack provider is exposing cinder v1 and v2 APIs and the previous logs from openstack_instances show the nova API is accessible.  Despite that, I never see any attempts on k8s part to communicate with cinder or nova to mount the volume.

Here are what I think are the relevant log messages regarding the failure to mount:

```
kubelet: I1020 06:51:11.840341   24027 desired_state_of_world_populator.go:323] Extracted volumeSpec (0x23a45e0) from bound PV (pvName "jk-test") and PVC (ClaimName "default"/"myclaim" pvcUID 51919dfb-96c9-11e6-8243-fa163ebfcd23)
kubelet: I1020 06:51:11.840424   24027 desired_state_of_world_populator.go:241] Added volume "jk-test" (volSpec="jk-test") for pod "f957f140-96cb-11e6-8243-fa163ebfcd23" to desired state.
kubelet: I1020 06:51:11.840474   24027 desired_state_of_world_populator.go:241] Added volume "default-token-js40f" (volSpec="default-token-js40f") for pod "f957f140-96cb-11e6-8243-fa163ebfcd23" to desired state.
kubelet: I1020 06:51:11.896176   24027 reconciler.go:201] Attempting to start VerifyControllerAttachedVolume for volume "kubernetes.io/cinder/48d2d1e6-e063-437a-855f-8b62b640a950" (spec.Name: "jk-test") pod "f957f140-96cb-11e6-8243-fa163ebfcd23" (UID: "f957f140-96cb-11e6-8243-fa163ebfcd23")
kubelet: I1020 06:51:11.896330   24027 reconciler.go:225] VerifyControllerAttachedVolume operation started for volume "kubernetes.io/cinder/48d2d1e6-e063-437a-855f-8b62b640a950" (spec.Name: "jk-test") pod "f957f140-96cb-11e6-8243-fa163ebfcd23" (UID: "f957f140-96cb-11e6-8243-fa163ebfcd23")
kubelet: I1020 06:51:11.896361   24027 reconciler.go:201] Attempting to start VerifyControllerAttachedVolume for volume "kubernetes.io/secret/f957f140-96cb-11e6-8243-fa163ebfcd23-default-token-js40f" (spec.Name: "default-token-js40f") pod "f957f140-96cb-11e6-8243-fa163ebfcd23" (UID: "f957f140-96cb-11e6-8243-fa163ebfcd23")
kubelet: I1020 06:51:11.896390   24027 reconciler.go:225] VerifyControllerAttachedVolume operation started for volume "kubernetes.io/secret/f957f140-96cb-11e6-8243-fa163ebfcd23-default-token-js40f" (spec.Name: "default-token-js40f") pod "f957f140-96cb-11e6-8243-fa163ebfcd23" (UID: "f957f140-96cb-11e6-8243-fa163ebfcd23")
kubelet: I1020 06:51:11.896420   24027 config.go:98] Looking for [api file], have seen map[file:{} api:{}]
kubelet: E1020 06:51:11.896566   24027 nestedpendingoperations.go:253] Operation for "\"kubernetes.io/cinder/48d2d1e6-e063-437a-855f-8b62b640a950\"" failed. No retries permitted until 2016-10-20 06:53:11.896529189 -0700 PDT (durationBeforeRetry 2m0s). Error: Volume "kubernetes.io/cinder/48d2d1e6-e063-437a-855f-8b62b640a950" (spec.Name: "jk-test") pod "f957f140-96cb-11e6-8243-fa163ebfcd23" (UID: "f957f140-96cb-11e6-8243-fa163ebfcd23") has not yet been added to the list of VolumesInUse in the node's volume status.
```

Is there a piece I am missing?  I've followed the instructions here: [k8s - mysql-cinder-pd example](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/mysql-cinder-pd) But haven't been able to get any communication.  As another datapoint I tried defining a Storage class as provided by k8s, here are the associated StorageClass and PVC files:

```
# cat cinderStorage.yaml
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: gold
provisioner: kubernetes.io/cinder
parameters:
  availability: nova
# cat dynamicPVC.yaml
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: dynamicclaim
  annotations:
    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: "gold"
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 8Gi
```

The StorageClass reports success, but when I try to create the PVC it gets stuck in the 'pending' state and reports 'no volume plugin matched':

```
# kubectl get storageclass
NAME      TYPE
gold      kubernetes.io/cinder
# kubectl describe pvc dynamicclaim
Name:           dynamicclaim
Namespace:      default
Status:         Pending
Volume:
Labels:         <none>
Capacity:
Access Modes:
Events:
  FirstSeen     LastSeen        Count   From                            SubobjectPath   Type            Reason                  Message
  ---------     --------        -----   ----                            -------------   --------        ------                  -------
  1d            15s             5867    {persistentvolume-controller }                  Warning         ProvisioningFailed      no volume plugin matched
```

This contradicts whats in the logs for plugins that were loaded:

```
grep plugins /var/log/messages
kubelet: I1019 11:39:41.382517   22435 plugins.go:56] Registering credential provider: .dockercfg
kubelet: I1019 11:39:41.382673   22435 plugins.go:355] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/aws-ebs"
kubelet: I1019 11:39:41.382685   22435 plugins.go:355] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/empty-dir"
kubelet: I1019 11:39:41.382691   22435 plugins.go:355] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/gce-pd"
kubelet: I1019 11:39:41.382698   22435 plugins.go:355] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/git-repo"
kubelet: I1019 11:39:41.382705   22435 plugins.go:355] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/host-path"
kubelet: I1019 11:39:41.382712   22435 plugins.go:355] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/nfs"
kubelet: I1019 11:39:41.382718   22435 plugins.go:355] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/secret"
kubelet: I1019 11:39:41.382725   22435 plugins.go:355] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/iscsi"
kubelet: I1019 11:39:41.382734   22435 plugins.go:355] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/glusterfs"
jk-kube2-master kubelet: I1019 11:39:41.382741   22435 plugins.go:355] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/rbd"
kubelet: I1019 11:39:41.382749   22435 plugins.go:355] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/cinder"
kubelet: I1019 11:39:41.382755   22435 plugins.go:355] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/quobyte"
kubelet: I1019 11:39:41.382762   22435 plugins.go:355] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/cephfs"
kubelet: I1019 11:39:41.382781   22435 plugins.go:355] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/downward-api"
kubelet: I1019 11:39:41.382798   22435 plugins.go:355] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/fc"
kubelet: I1019 11:39:41.382804   22435 plugins.go:355] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/flocker"
kubelet: I1019 11:39:41.382822   22435 plugins.go:355] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/azure-file"
kubelet: I1019 11:39:41.382839   22435 plugins.go:355] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/configmap"
kubelet: I1019 11:39:41.382846   22435 plugins.go:355] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume"
kubelet: I1019 11:39:41.382853   22435 plugins.go:355] Loaded volume plugin "kubernetes.io/azure-disk"
```

And I have the nova and cinder clients installed on my machine:

```
# which nova
/usr/bin/nova
# which cinder
/usr/bin/cinder
```

Any help is appreciated, I'm sure I'm missing something simple here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The cinder volumes work for sure with Kubernetes 1.5.0 and 1.5.3 (I think they also worked on 1.4.6 on which I was first experimenting, I don't know about previous versions).

### Short answer

In your Pod yaml file you were missing: `volumeMounts:` section.

### Longer answer

#### First possibility: no PV or PVC

Actually, when you already have an existing cinder volume, you can just use a Pod (or Deployment), no PV or PVC is needed. Example:

`apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: vol-test
  labels:
    fullname: vol-test
spec:
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        fullname: vol-test
    spec:
      containers:
        - name:  nginx
          image: "nginx:1.11.6-alpine"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - echo "heey-testing" > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html && nginx "-g daemon off;"
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
          volumeMounts:
            - name: data
              mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/
      volumes:
        - name: data
          cinder:
            volumeID: e143368a-440a-400f-b8a4-dd2f46c51888`

This will create a Deployment and a Pod. The cinder volume will be mounted into the nginx container. To verify that you are using a volume, you can edit a file inside nginx container, inside `/usr/share/nginx/html/` directory and stop the container. Kubernetes will  create a new container and inside it, the files in `/usr/share/nginx/html/` directory will be the same as they were in the stopped container.

After you delete the Deployment resource, the cinder volume is not deleted, but it is detached from a vm.

#### Second possibility: with PV and PVC

Other possibility, if you already have an existing cinder volume, you can use PV and PVC resources. You said you want to use a storage class, though Kubernetes docs allow not using it:

> A PV with no annotation or its class annotation set to "" has no class and can only be bound to PVCs that request no particular class

[source](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/persistent-volumes/#persistent-volumes)

An example storage-class is:

`kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  # to be used as value for annotation:
  # volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class
  name: cinder-gluster-hdd
provisioner: kubernetes.io/cinder
parameters:
  # openstack volume type
  type: gluster_hdd
  # openstack availability zone
  availability: nova`

Then, you use your existing cinder volume with ID 48d2d1e6-e063-437a-855f-8b62b640a950 in a PV:

`apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  # name of a pv resource visible in Kubernetes, not the name of
  # a cinder volume
  name: pv0001
  labels:
    pv-first-label: "123"
    pv-second-label: abc
  annotations:
    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: cinder-gluster-hdd
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  cinder:
    # ID of cinder volume
    volumeID: 48d2d1e6-e063-437a-855f-8b62b640a950`

Then create a PVC, which labels selector matches the labels of the PV:

`kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: vol-test
  labels:
    pvc-first-label: "123"
    pvc-second-label: abc
  annotations:
    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: "cinder-gluster-hdd"
spec:
  accessModes:
    # the volume can be mounted as read-write by a single node
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: "1Gi"
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pv-first-label: "123"
      pv-second-label: abc`

and then a Deployment:

`kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: vol-test
  labels:
    fullname: vol-test
    environment: testing
spec:
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        fullname: vol-test
        environment: testing
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "is_worker": "true"
      containers:
        - name:  nginx-exist-vol
          image: "nginx:1.11.6-alpine"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - echo "heey-testing" > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html && nginx "-g daemon off;"
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
          volumeMounts:
            - name: data
              mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/
      volumes:
        - name: data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: vol-test`

After you delete the k8s resources, the cinder volume is not deleted, but it is detached from a vm.

Using a PV lets you set `persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy`.

#### Third possibility: no cinder volume created

If you don't have a cinder volume created, Kubernetes can create it for you. You have to then provide a PVC resource. I won't describe this variant, since it was not asked for.

#### Disclaimer

I suggest that anyone interested in finding the best option should experiment themselves and compare the methods. Also, I used the labels names like `pv-first-label` and `pvc-first-label` only for better understanding reasons. You can use e.g. `first-label` everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I get the suspicion that the dynamic StorageClass approach is not working, because the Cinder provisioner is not implemented yet, given the following statement in the docs (http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/persistent-volumes/#provisioner):

> Storage classes have a provisioner that determines what volume plugin is used for provisioning PVs. This field must be specified. During beta, the available provisioner types are kubernetes.io/aws-ebs and kubernetes.io/gce-pd

As for why the static method using Cinder volume IDs is not working, I'm not sure. I'm running into the exact same problem. Kubernetes 1.2 seems to work fine, 1.3 and 1.4 do not. This seems to coincide with the major change in PersistentVolume handling in 1.3-beta2 (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/26801):

> A new volume manager was introduced in kubelet that synchronizes volume mount/unmount (and attach/detach, if attach/detach controller is not enabled). (#26801, @saad-ali)
>
> This eliminates the race conditions between the pod creation loop and the orphaned volumes loops. It also removes the unmount/detach from the syncPod() path so volume clean up never blocks the syncPod loop.