# How the kubernetes cinder volume plugin works?

Tags: go, kubernetes, openstack, docker-volume, openstack-cinder

I'm new to k8s, and recently, I read the cinder volume plugin source code:
[cinder volume plugin](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/pkg/volume/cinder).

I don't know how the plugin works, and how it communicates with cinder?
And I don't find the request and response in code.

Does the cinder volume plugin call cinder API or other ways?

Answer (score 1):

cinder volume is a [persistent volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/persistent-volumes/), more precisely one of the persistent volume [storage classes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/persistent-volumes/#storageclasses).

> Each StorageClass contains the fields provisioner and parameters, which are used when a PersistentVolume belonging to the class needs to be dynamically provisioned.

Cinder specifically is an [Openstack volume type](http://docs.openstack.org/admin-guide/dashboard-manage-volumes.html).
It is an [OpenStack Block Storage Cinder](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Cinder), which:

> - implements services and libraries to provide on demand, self-service access to Block Storage resources.
> - Provides Software Defined Block Storage via abstraction and automation on top of various traditional backend block storage devices.

You can see how Kubernetes uses cinder in [`pkg/volume/cinder/cinder_test.go`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/volume/cinder/cinder_test.go).
However, as mentioned in "[Kubernetes Cinder volumes do not mount with cloud-provider=openstack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40841681/6309)":

> the the Cinder provisioner is not implemented yet, given the following statement in the docs ([StorageClasses Provisioner](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/persistent-volumes/#provisioner)):
>
> > During beta, the available provisioner types are `kubernetes.io/aws-ebs` and `kubernetes.io/gce-pd`

So no "`kubernetes.io/cinder`" yet.
Yet, [Ewa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4457564/ewa) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41658969/how-the-kubernetes-cinder-volume-plugin-works/41659037?noredirect=1#comment72464885_41659037) making it work: see "[Kubernetes Cinder volumes do not mount with `cloud-provider=openstack`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42670021/6309)" as an example.

Comment: eh,I've not run a cinder example,I just read the source code.  can you tell me how the plugin works? and how it communicate with cinder? I'm very confused.    thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Lance.yang Exactly. My point is, should you try to run a cinder example, it might not work from kubernetes

Comment: I don't know how the cinder volume plugin works, but I want you to know that it works. For sure in Kubernetes 1.5.3, both dynamic and static way.

Comment: @Ewa Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility (with a link to your recent answer)

Answer (score 0):

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46067591/how-to-use-openstack-cinder-to-create-storage-class-and-dynamically-provision-pe). Kubernetes has configuration(`--cloud-config` paramter) on how to connect cloud provider like OpenStack to operate Load Balance IP & Block Storage.