# How to use OpenStack Cinder to create storage class and dynamically provision persistent volume in Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, openstack, cinder

Recently when practicing kubernetes , I found there is no doc and example specifically explaining how to use cinder correctly in kubernetes.

So how to setup cinder to be used in kubernetes ?

Answer (score 8):

I did some experiment and worked out how to setup cinder with kubernetes. Just find a suitable to document and share.

**Preparation**

- kubernetes cluster
- openstack environment and make sure cinder service is available

**Background**

From my investigation, component `kube-controller-manager` is responsible for loading volume plugins and related in Kubernetes. So we could make cinder available by adjusting `kube-controller-manager` configuration.

**Steps**

1. **Prepare `cloud.conf` file to contain your openstack creds**

Prepare your openstack creds and saved as a file , for example `/etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf` in kubernetes control panel which `kube-controller-manager` locates. The following is example for `cloud.conf`

```
[Global]
auth-url=$your_openstack_auth_url
username=$your_openstack_user
password=$your_user_pw
region=$your_openstack_reigon
tenant-name=$your_project_name
domain-name=$your_domain_name
ca-file=$your_openstack_ca
```

Most could be found from your `stackrc` file. And `ca-file` item is optional, depending on if your openstack auth url is `http` or `https`

2. **Adjust `kube-controller-manager` start configuration**

This link is a full detail options for `kube-controller-manager` (https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kube-controller-manager/)

Actually we should add two extra parameters based on your current one

```
--cloud-provider=openstack
--cloud-config=/etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf
```

There are mainly two ways to start `kube-controller-manager` : 1) using systemd 2) using static pod .

Just one tips, if you are using static pod for `kube-controller-manager` , make sure you have mount all files such as cloud.conf or openstack ca file into your container.

**Verification**

We will create a storageclass, and use this storageclass to create persistent volume dynamically.

1. Create a storageclass named `standard`:

**demo-sc.yml:**

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: standard
  annotations:
    storageclass.beta.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: EnsureExists
provisioner: kubernetes.io/cinder
```

Using command `kubectl create -f demo-sc.yml` to create and using command `kubectl get sc` to verify if it created correctly

```
NAME                 TYPE
standard (default)   kubernetes.io/cinder
```

2. Create a PersistentVolumeClaim to use StorageClass provison a Persistent Volume in Cinder:

**demo-pvc.yml:**

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: cinder-claim
  annotations:
    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: "standard"
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

Creating PVC by `kubectl create -f demo-pvc.yml`

And now checking by command `kubectl get pvc`

```
NAME           STATUS    VOLUME                                         CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
cinder-claim   Bound     pvc-5dd3d62e-9204-11e7-bc43-fa163e0e0379   1Gi          RWO           standard       23h
```

And in openstack environment, checking by command `cinder list | grep pvc-5dd3d62e-9204-11e7-bc43-fa163e0e0379`

```
    root@ds0114:~# cinder list | grep pvc-5dd3d62e-9204-11e7-bc43- fa163e0e0379
| ddd8066d-2e16-4cb2-a89e-cd9d5b99ef1b | available | kubernetes-dynamic- pvc-5dd3d62e-9204-11e7-bc43-fa163e0e0379 |  1   |   CEPH_SSD  |  false   |                                       |
```

So now StorageClass is working well using Cinder in Kubernetes.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot for your great share!
The solution works for me (`K8S 1.14.3`, `OpenStack Queen`), and I just added snippets of parameter/volumeMounts/volume like below:

**Parameter**:

```
- --cloud-provider=openstack  
- --cloud-config=/etc/kubernetes/cloud-config
```

**volumeMounts**:

```
-- mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/cloud-config  
   name: cloud  
   readOnly: true
```

**volume**:

```
-- hostPath:  
     path: /etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf  
     type: FileOrCreate  
   name: cloud
```